# Yum Hangs on "Setting up repositories"

Tags: centos, yum

When running the following command, yum hangs on `Setting up repositories`.

```
[vagrant@centos48 yum.repos.d]$ sudo yum install emacs
Setting up Install Process
Setting up repositories
```

yum.conf

```
[vagrant@centos48 ~]$ cat /etc/yum.conf 
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
pkgpolicy=newest
installonlypkgs=kernel kernel-smp kernel-devel kernel-smp-devel kernel-largesmp kernel-largesmp-devel kernel-hugemem kernel-hugemem-devel
distroverpkg=centos-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1
retries=20
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1

proxy= [intentionally not listed]

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
```

CentOS-Base.repo

Note that I got the same error as before when commenting out `[base]`'s `baseurl`, but leaving `mirrorlist` uncommented.

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# This file uses a new mirrorlist system developed by Lance Davis for CentOS.
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
priority=1
protect=1

#released updates
[update]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
priority=1
protect=1

#packages used/produced in the build but not released
[addons]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Addons
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=addons
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/addons/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
priority=1
protect=1

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
priority=1
protect=1

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
priority=2
protect=1
```

Comment: Would you include your `/etc/yum.conf` and repo files? (`/etc/yum.repos.d/*`?)  Is the host on an internal network without Internet access?

Comment: What does  `yum -v install emacs` say?  Also run `yum repolist`

Comment: Actually, I didn't have my proxy set up correctly. But I got this error next, `not using ftp, http[s], or file for repos, skipping - 4 is not a valid release or hasnt been released yet.`

Comment: As Aaron asked, Pasting your yum.conf and all other repo files /etc/yum.repos.d/* will really help us to understand and answer your query.

Comment: Folks, thank you very much. I'm going to install CentOS 5 (I'm using vagrant) and try again. I'll post my yum repo files if I still have problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your server is running an *old* version of CentOS 4, which went [End-of-Life in February 2012.](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2012-February/018462.html) The files have been moved to the [CentOS Vault](http://vault.centos.org/). Your repo files would need to be modified in order to continue to use this OS with the YUM framework.

You can update your `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` file to point to the new location as so:

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# This file uses a new mirrorlist system developed by Lance Davis for CentOS.
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/4.9/os/$basearch
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4

#released updates 
[update]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/4.9/updates/$basearch
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-centos4
```

Comment: wwyd (what would you do?) to fix it

Comment: @Kevin Can you run `cat /etc/issue`?

Comment: `[vagrant@centos48 yum.repos.d]$ sudo cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 4.8 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m`

Comment: Substitute "4.8" for "4.9" in my example above, then.

Comment: I followed what you said for the addons and extras sections too. Success thanks.

[vagrant@centos48 yum.repos.d]$ which emacs
/usr/bin/emacs

Comment: Excellent. I think this approach would also allow you to move to CentOS 4.9.